# Problem with converting a solo chain to a parachain in Substrate

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rust, relay-chain

I am trying to convert my solo chain to parachain but I am facing some trouble. First, I ran parachain template as well as the relaychain template of Polkadot and it worked fine. Next, I just copied my pallets from my solo chain to the parachain refered above and built. Then I ran my code and on https://polkadot.js.org/apps I didn't see my custom pallets. I also tried to add more extrinsics of the pallet template but I also did't see it on https://polkadot.js.org/apps. I really appreciate the help from all of you. Thanks very much.

The pallet template that I have added an extrinsic named "do_more":

[image]

This is no change with the pallet template on the website

[image]

Comment: Without something concrete to look at it is impossible to help sadly. Please provide some minimal viable example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DanShields I have added some images to my question. I hope that it helps to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is probably that you have added your new pallets, but have not properly reset or upgraded your chain.

The easiest thing to do is make sure to reset your chain with the latest build. So:

1. Rebuild your node with the new runtime code: `cargo build --release`
2. Run `./target/release/template-parachain purge-chain --dev`
3. Run `./target/release/template-parachain --dev`

You might need to adjust the commands based on how you run your node, but the main idea is to `purge-chain` and run the latest binary with the latest code.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have solved my problem